# How to show a message and delete it each time the route changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, single-page-application

I have a `message` attribute in my redux store, and the message it holds there is shown on top of the "page". Such as "Your request has been accepted", etc. However, whenever the user chooses to go to a different "page", the message should go away.

In other words, I want something similar to `django.contrib.messages`, where the message lasts only until the next request. Except that in an "SPA" there's no request, there's only the React Router switching "pages".

I thought this should be implemented at React Router (e.g. by somehow having a custom function be run at each page transition), but I don't really know.

Is there a standard way of achieving this?

Comment: What version of react-router are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history lib with react-router v4. I don`t have all your code but you can do something like I show above

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'

const history = createHistory();

history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(location);
  // something to cleanup the message can be a function or a state change
});

<Router history={history}>
 // router rules
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-router-redux` that will keep your state sync with your route. after that you can set a reducer that catch `LOCATION_CHANGE` unset the message attribute on your store.

This solution will reset the message after each change on the history.

For a detailed documentation check https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux